# Mathematical explanation of the output sequence

Tags: logic, recursion

I have a recursive function that gives some sequence:

```
def f(n):
  if n <= 0:
    return 0
  else:
    return 1-(n%2)+f(n/2)
```

Which returns a number. So I need to say what's the logic in this number, and is some logical explanation to this numbers cause, for ex, the number from this function:

```
def f(n):
  if n <= 0:
    return 0
  else:
    return (n%2)+f(n/2)
```

is the sum of digits in the "n" number in binary numerical system representation: 
n = 12 == 1100 -> so f(12) return 2, cause 1+1+0+0 = 2. But what's the logic in the first function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to say it is that the second function is counting ones in the binary representation of $n$. Do a little experimenting with the first function:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|r}
n&f(n)&n\text{ in binary}\\ \hline
0&0&0\\
1&0&1\\
2&1&10\\
3&0&11\\
4&2&100\\
5&1&101\\
6&1&110\\
7&0&111\\
8&3&1000
\end{array}$$

It does something very similar to the second function, and once you spot it, you should be able to convince yourself that it really does perform that operation.

Comment: Sorry, but i didn't understand what the first function gives. For ex: n = 3 in binary equals to "0011", but f(3) returns 0. Why?

Comment: I think you've mixed up my functions =)

Comment: @John: Sorry: I reversed *first* and *second* in my explanation. I’ve fixed it now.

Comment: Ok, now i got it! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Since `(n%2)` is being replaced by `1-(n%2)`, it replaces `1` with `0` and `0` with `1` in the binary representation of $n$.